# Make Ball bounce around in a cube infinitely

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, soft-body

I am trying to make a soft body ball bounce infinitely off of all the walls within a cube. Unfortunately I have not had any success with this. Everything loses momentum and stops, even with all dampening turned off and friction set to 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide your blend file to check it out...

I have made this which is bouncing pretty long...i just checked until 2000 frames...should be (hopefully) enough.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris! That is super helpful. I thought I had similar settings but eventually my simulation just loses momentum. I will study your file more closely to see what it is Im doing differently.

Comment: You are welcome!